# Как сделать, чтобы функция js вызываемая с одной html страницы работала на другой html странице?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, функции

Есть функция addToCart , которая должна добавлять товары в корзину.

Функция вызывается с основной страницы:

<баттон id="btn-add-to-cart1" onclick="addToCart()">Add to Cart</баттон>

Есть другая html страница, которая является корзиной

Как сделать, чтобы эта функция с помощью document.createElement добавляла элементы именно на эту страницу , а не туда, откуда вызывается

Comment: Если страница 1 является родителем страницы 2, имеет ссылку на страницу 2 и они с одного домена - скрипт страницы 1 может через ссылку на страницу 2 менять ее ДОМ дерево.

Comment: В учебнике про такое есть информация - https://learn.javascript.ru/window-methods